# Does satan have horns and pitchfork?

Tags: revelation, daniel, satan

I was told by one of my friends that Satan does have a pitchfork and horns.

And I said to him laughing, "Satan doesn't look anything like how they show in movies and television".

He replied that he(satan) does.
Read Daniel and revelation.

But I couldn't find anything supporting his statement.

Comment: Note: This is a good question but is probably more appropriate for https://christianity.stackexchange.com as it is not concerned with expositing a particular text. 

This site attempts to provide some background to the imagery: https://aleteia.org/2017/10/17/why-is-satan-depicted-with-horns-red-tights-and-a-pitchfork/  However, sometimes "Satan" is used to refer to human adversaries so without a text, this question must be qualified by a specific text in order to be suitable for exegesis.

Comment: can you move the question there? or do I have to repost it?

Comment: Since your question already has answers I don't think it can be moved now. Maybe check the help center: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: yeah. I pretty much agree with Ray's answer

Comment: Do you know how to upvote and mark an answer as "The Answer"? If not, please see:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I do know. I'm on other forums as well. only new to this one . I'm just waiting for Ray's reply to my last query only then I'll hit the green tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is perhaps referring to Daniel 7:7:

> After this I saw in the night visions, and behold a fourth beast, dreadful and terrible, and strong exceedingly; and it had great iron teeth: it devoured and brake in pieces, and stamped the residue with the feet of it: and it was diverse from all the beasts that were before it; and it had ten horns.

Note that this was "a vision", not reality.
And a few verses later, Daniel 7:24 explains what the symbolic horns meant:

> And the ten horns out of this kingdom are ten kings ...

Similarly, Revelation 13:11 says:

> And I beheld another beast coming up out of the earth; and he had two horns like a lamb, and he spake as a dragon.

But Revelation is a symbolic vision, not to be taken literally.
Horns are used to represent power, as in Revelation 17:12, which explains:

> And the ten horns which thou sawest are ten kings ...

(Don't accept individual verses out of context.  Let scripture interpret itself.)

---

As for depictions of Satan (and his demons), 2 Corinthians 11:14-15 says:

> And no marvel; for Satan himself is transformed into an angel of light. Therefore it is no great thing if his ministers also be transformed as the ministers of righteousness ...

As an angel, Satan can appear as whatever he wants.
It's obviously to his advantage for him and his ministers to appear as attractive, charismatic, trustworthy, righteous people.

His portrayal with horns etc. is symbolic, and intended to scare us away from him.

On the other hand, some suggest that this false depiction might actually be a tool of the devil himself.
In "The Screwtape Letters", C. S. Lewis's demonic character offers a suggestion to another demon:

> The fact that ‘devils’ are predominately comic figures in the modern imagination will help you. If any faint suspicion of your existence begins to arise in his mind, suggest to him a picture of something in red tights, and persuade him that since he cannot believe in that (it is an old textbook method of confusing them) he therefore cannot believe in you.

Earlier, in 1864, Charles Baudelaire, in "The Generous Gambler" stated:

> The loveliest trick of the Devil is to persuade you that he does not exist!

Comment: Okay this clears who the horned beings were. But what about dragon? Was it Satan? Cz Satan was already depicted as a serpent. And there's very much resemblance between serpent and dragon.

Comment: A dragon is a serpent. Serpent means a large reptile.

Comment: @StewartGilliganGriffin asks "what about dragon?".  There are many references to the dragon in Revelation.  In particular, 12:9 says "And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world ...".

Answer (score 1):

Stewart, you couldn't find anything supporting [his] statement because it is not a factual statement. There are times when I look at my plate and I could "swear" I see the devil, and then my vision clears up and I realize it's just a delicious slice of Tiramisu. Seriously, I agree with Ray Butterworth's Biblically substantive answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Leviticus 16:7-10 (KJV)
>   And he shall take the two goats, and present them before the Lord at the door of the tabernacle of the congregation. And Aaron shall cast lots upon the two goats; one lot for the Lord, and the other lot for the scapegoat. And Aaron shall bring the goat upon which the Lord's lot fell, and offer him for a sin offering. But the goat, on which the lot fell to be the scapegoat, shall be presented alive before the Lord, to make an atonement with him, and to let him go for a **scapegoat** into the wilderness.

Goats have horns right? If you know the origin of the pentagram, it is the head of a goat, with the two horns at the top, the ears flopping down, and the chin pointing down. Yes, that one can appear as anything, so no they may not have literal horns; based on your question it is entirely figurative.

Horns however imply power and authority. Does the enemy have power and auth: Yes. Ergo they/he have/has "horns".